# Is my Inverse Kinematics bone working correctly?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

[image]
Take a look at the bone selected.

[image]
Now take a look at the selected bone. Shouldn't it be moving down as shown in the video tutorial I have been watching?

[image]
https://youtu.be/jp_SqjB0468?t=14m22s

Comment: Please edit your question without asking two times the same issue https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98431/is-my-inverse-kinematics-not-working-correctly-or-is-it-working-correctly

Comment: This is not the same question if you carefully read the two questions they are different.